# Cannot access remote CentOS Apache web server

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, ping

I am configuring a web server on a remote virtual machine running Centos 7. I can access the machine via ssh, but once I installed and configured Apache for a simple test, I cannot access the remote web page.

I tried to ping the remote IP from my local machine (ubuntu). I got this message and nothing more happened:

```
PING <remote ip> (<remote ip>) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

If I remotely shut down the VM, I get

```
From <remote ip> icmp_seq=138 Destination Host Unreachable
```

When I stop the ping task, I get

```
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2031ms
```

My iptables rules are the following:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   45  3148 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:80
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Disabling SELinux does not work. What could be the problem?

UPDATE: I tried the following

- firewall-cmd --add-service=http --zone=public --permanent
- `$ nmap -Pn -PS80 <remote ip>` gives the following (however apache is not reachable)

  Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-01-27 19:18 CET

  Nmap scan report for ip-

  Host is up (0.058s latency).

  Not shown: 999 filtered ports

  PORT   STATE SERVICE

  22/tcp open  ssh

Comment: Is there a firewall running?

Comment: Why would you expect disabling SELinux to make this work?

Comment: Crystal ball error 0007

Comment: Instead of just downvoting the question, you could suggest a way to improve it...

Answer (score 1):

On a Centos 7 in a default configuration, after installing a new network service you must also configure the software firewall to allow it, or else it won't be reachable.

To allow HTTP immediately:

```
# firewall-cmd --add-service=http --zone=public
```

To make the setting permanent:

```
# firewall-cmd --add-service=http --zone=public --permanent
```

To make the settings both immediately effective and persistent over reboots, you must use the `firewall-cmd` command twice: once without the `--permanent` option and once with it.

Is that `iptables` output from your Ubuntu or from the Centos VM? The byte and package counts on TCP port 80 are still zeroes, indicating that no incoming HTTP connection attempts have even reached that system. If that was from Centos, that and your `nmap` output together confirm that there is definitely something between those two systems blocking the HTTP connection.

Comment: I did it but this did not fix the problem

Comment: Edited my answer in light of your update.

Comment: what other checks can I make?